# Azure Cosmos DB SQL API

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to run this query

```sql
    SELECT c.foodGroup,
    c.description,
    ch.amount,
    ch.weightInGrams
    ***--ch.description***
    FROM c
    join ch in c.servings
     where c.id = '21272'
```

The `weightingrams` and `description` are key value pairs in `servings`. The value `weightingrams` shows up but the `description` doesn't show up.

I have tried `description` and `[description]` but it throws an error saying that `description` has been used more than once. What's the way around for this?

This is in reference to `food.json` as provided by cosmosdb try sql api.

Also providing the json:

```json
{
    "id": "21272",
    "description": "PIZZA HUT 12\" Cheese Pizza, Pan Crust",
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "pizza hut 12\" cheese pizza"
        },
        {
            "name": "pan crust"
        }
    ],
    "version": 1,
    "manufacturerName": "Pizza Hut, Inc.",
    "foodGroup": "Fast Foods",
    "nutrients": [
        {
            "id": "203",
            "description": "Protein",
            "nutritionValue": 11.73,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "208",
            "description": "Energy",
            "nutritionValue": 280,
            "units": "kcal"
        },
        {
            "id": "209",
            "description": "Starch",
            "nutritionValue": 21.22,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "210",
            "description": "Sucrose",
            "nutritionValue": 0,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "211",
            "description": "Glucose (dextrose)",
            "nutritionValue": 0.41,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "304",
            "description": "Magnesium, Mg",
            "nutritionValue": 21,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "305",
            "description": "Phosphorus, P",
            "nutritionValue": 241,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "315",
            "description": "Manganese, Mn",
            "nutritionValue": 0.305,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "341",
            "description": "Tocopherol, beta",
            "nutritionValue": 0.05,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "342",
            "description": "Tocopherol, gamma",
            "nutritionValue": 3.48,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "401",
            "description": "Vitamin C, total ascorbic acid",
            "nutritionValue": 0,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "418",
            "description": "Vitamin B-12",
            "nutritionValue": 0.64,
            "units": "µg"
        },
        {
            "id": "501",
            "description": "Tryptophan",
            "nutritionValue": 0.125,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "504",
            "description": "Leucine",
            "nutritionValue": 1.044,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "601",
            "description": "Cholesterol",
            "nutritionValue": 21,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "618",
            "description": "18:2 undifferentiated",
            "nutritionValue": 2.433,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "619",
            "description": "18:3 undifferentiated",
            "nutritionValue": 0.304,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "620",
            "description": "20:4 undifferentiated",
            "nutritionValue": 0.015,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "625",
            "description": "14:1",
            "nutritionValue": 0.053,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "307",
            "description": "Sodium, Na",
            "nutritionValue": 624,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "309",
            "description": "Zinc, Zn",
            "nutritionValue": 1.63,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "318",
            "description": "Vitamin A, IU",
            "nutritionValue": 260,
            "units": "IU"
        },
        {
            "id": "514",
            "description": "Aspartic acid",
            "nutritionValue": 0.753,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "516",
            "description": "Glycine",
            "nutritionValue": 0.322,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "610",
            "description": "10:0",
            "nutritionValue": 0.187,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "645",
            "description": "Fatty acids, total monounsaturated",
            "nutritionValue": 3.213,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "689",
            "description": "20:3 undifferentiated",
            "nutritionValue": 0,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "204",
            "description": "Total lipid (fat)",
            "nutritionValue": 12.56,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "205",
            "description": "Carbohydrate, by difference",
            "nutritionValue": 29.93,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "207",
            "description": "Ash",
            "nutritionValue": 2.39,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "212",
            "description": "Fructose",
            "nutritionValue": 0.42,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "255",
            "description": "Water",
            "nutritionValue": 43.4,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "268",
            "description": "Energy",
            "nutritionValue": 1170,
            "units": "kJ"
        },
        {
            "id": "269",
            "description": "Sugars, total",
            "nutritionValue": 3.21,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "306",
            "description": "Potassium, K",
            "nutritionValue": 168,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "323",
            "description": "Vitamin E (alpha-tocopherol)",
            "nutritionValue": 1.06,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "343",
            "description": "Tocopherol, delta",
            "nutritionValue": 1.15,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "344",
            "description": "Tocotrienol, alpha",
            "nutritionValue": 0.05,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "503",
            "description": "Isoleucine",
            "nutritionValue": 0.518,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "506",
            "description": "Methionine",
            "nutritionValue": 0.266,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "617",
            "description": "18:1 undifferentiated",
            "nutritionValue": 2.997,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "626",
            "description": "16:1 undifferentiated",
            "nutritionValue": 0.124,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "653",
            "description": "17:0",
            "nutritionValue": 0.048,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "303",
            "description": "Iron, Fe",
            "nutritionValue": 1.86,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "347",
            "description": "Tocotrienol, delta",
            "nutritionValue": 0,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "406",
            "description": "Niacin",
            "nutritionValue": 3.91,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "430",
            "description": "Vitamin K (phylloquinone)",
            "nutritionValue": 15.5,
            "units": "µg"
        },
        {
            "id": "502",
            "description": "Threonine",
            "nutritionValue": 0.379,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "509",
            "description": "Tyrosine",
            "nutritionValue": 0.479,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "512",
            "description": "Histidine",
            "nutritionValue": 0.326,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "517",
            "description": "Proline",
            "nutritionValue": 1.253,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "606",
            "description": "Fatty acids, total saturated",
            "nutritionValue": 5.184,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "614",
            "description": "18:0",
            "nutritionValue": 1.203,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "851",
            "description": "18:3 n-3 c,c,c (ALA)",
            "nutritionValue": 0.304,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "213",
            "description": "Lactose",
            "nutritionValue": 0.47,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "405",
            "description": "Riboflavin",
            "nutritionValue": 0.251,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "511",
            "description": "Arginine",
            "nutritionValue": 0.451,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "518",
            "description": "Serine",
            "nutritionValue": 0.648,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "613",
            "description": "16:0",
            "nutritionValue": 2.611,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "615",
            "description": "20:0",
            "nutritionValue": 0.025,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "697",
            "description": "15:1",
            "nutritionValue": 0,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "287",
            "description": "Galactose",
            "nutritionValue": 0.07,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "317",
            "description": "Selenium, Se",
            "nutritionValue": 19.4,
            "units": "µg"
        },
        {
            "id": "410",
            "description": "Pantothenic acid",
            "nutritionValue": 0.285,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "429",
            "description": "Dihydrophylloquinone",
            "nutritionValue": 0,
            "units": "µg"
        },
        {
            "id": "513",
            "description": "Alanine",
            "nutritionValue": 0.386,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "515",
            "description": "Glutamic acid",
            "nutritionValue": 3.323,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "609",
            "description": "8:0",
            "nutritionValue": 0.082,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "611",
            "description": "12:0",
            "nutritionValue": 0.212,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "628",
            "description": "20:1",
            "nutritionValue": 0.027,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "646",
            "description": "Fatty acids, total polyunsaturated",
            "nutritionValue": 2.752,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "672",
            "description": "20:2 n-6 c,c",
            "nutritionValue": 0,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "291",
            "description": "Fiber, total dietary",
            "nutritionValue": 1.7,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "301",
            "description": "Calcium, Ca",
            "nutritionValue": 208,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "312",
            "description": "Copper, Cu",
            "nutritionValue": 0.101,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "346",
            "description": "Tocotrienol, gamma",
            "nutritionValue": 0,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "415",
            "description": "Vitamin B-6",
            "nutritionValue": 0.107,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "508",
            "description": "Phenylalanine",
            "nutritionValue": 0.615,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "612",
            "description": "14:0",
            "nutritionValue": 0.723,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "685",
            "description": "18:3 n-6 c,c,c",
            "nutritionValue": 0,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "687",
            "description": "17:1",
            "nutritionValue": 0.012,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "214",
            "description": "Maltose",
            "nutritionValue": 1.83,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "319",
            "description": "Retinol",
            "nutritionValue": 73,
            "units": "µg"
        },
        {
            "id": "320",
            "description": "Vitamin A, RAE",
            "nutritionValue": 73,
            "units": "µg"
        },
        {
            "id": "345",
            "description": "Tocotrienol, beta",
            "nutritionValue": 0,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "404",
            "description": "Thiamin",
            "nutritionValue": 0.243,
            "units": "mg"
        },
        {
            "id": "505",
            "description": "Lysine",
            "nutritionValue": 0.693,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "507",
            "description": "Cystine",
            "nutritionValue": 0.156,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "510",
            "description": "Valine",
            "nutritionValue": 0.658,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "624",
            "description": "22:0",
            "nutritionValue": 0.018,
            "units": "g"
        },
        {
            "id": "652",
            "description": "15:0",
            "nutritionValue": 0.074,
            "units": "g"
        }
    ],
    "servings": [
        {
            "amount": 1,
            "description": "slice",
            "weightInGrams": 100
        },
        {
            "amount": 1,
            "description": "pizza",
            "weightInGrams": 728
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried description and [description] but it throws an error
> saying that decription has been used more than once.

This is due to your name of property `decription` is duplicate, you can try this sql:

```
SELECT 
    c.foodGroup,
    c.description,
    ch.amount,
    ch.weightInGrams,
    ch.description as ch_description
FROM c
join ch in c.servings
where c.id = '21272'
```